# FSSM -> gem install rb-inotify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to get an application working. I installed all the required gems using bundle install. But when I try to start the server it shows the following two lines

> FSSM -> An optimized backend is available for this platform!
>
> FSSM ->     gem install rb-inotify

and then the server starts. The application is working fine but I want to know why it show me these two lines? Any one can explain or help me how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the application you are running is running older versions of a gem and was in deprecation phase when the particular gem was included.

Comment: Yes exactly the application was running an older versions.. After updating the gems the problem is solved.. Thanks Sairam

Answer (score 1):

fssm lets you subscribe to changes in the filesystem, on linux it uses the native inotify api, if this is not available, such as on windows, a fallback solution is used by frequently polling the folder of interest and "manually" checking if changes have occured, which costs more resources and is unnecessary.

The fix is to add rb-inotify to your applications Gemfile